# Angular Material 13.3.7 mat-calendar - Can you make it readonly?

Tags: angular-material

I'm adding an inline calendar using:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-calendar [(selected)]="selectedDate"></mat-calendar>
</mat-card>
```

I would like to make the inline calendar read-only. That is, the user can navigate but cannot change the dates.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell:not(.mat-calendar-body-disabled)>.mat-calendar-body-cell-content:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected):not(.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical),
.mat-calendar-body-disabled>.mat-calendar-body-cell-content:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected):not(.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical) {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Using pointer-events helped. I couldn't get your example to work. However, I modified to the following and it works unless someone tries to change the year.
 .mat-calendar-body-cell-container {
  pointer-events: none;
}